# FindFirstChangeNotification for a removed folder

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filesystems

I'm seeing a strange behavior that I didn't see in the documentation. Here's my test code:

```
HANDLE h = FindFirstChangeNotification(L"test_dir", FALSE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE);
printf("%p %u\n", h, GetLastError());

while (true) {
    WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE);
    BOOL b = FindNextChangeNotification(h);
    printf("%d %u\n", b, GetLastError());
}
```

The code works as expected by printing a message every time I modify a file in the folder. But if I remove the folder, it enters an infinite loop, returning success every time.

I'm afraid that if a user removes the target folder by mistake or for any other reason, the program is going to be spinning the CPU, and I'll have no way to detect this. I can check whether the folder is gone, but it doesn't feel like a clean solution, and also it can be recreated, in which case the loop keeps spinning.

## Update with a clarification

When the folder is removed for good, I get an error from `FindNextChangeNotification` as I expected. But if it's **removed to the recycle bin**, I get an infinite loop.

Comment: what sense at all use `FindFirstChangeNotification` and `FindNextChangeNotification` instead `ReadDirectoryChangesW` or `NtNotifyChangeDirectoryFile` ?

Comment: It's simpler and I don't need the extra information `ReadDirectoryChangesW` provides.

Comment: i not think that it "simpler" compare to `ReadDirectoryChangesW` (faster visa versa) and less functional and efficient

Comment: `FindFirstChangeNotification` ends up calling `NtNotifyChangeDirectoryFile`, so isn't it the same in the end? The former looks like a simple wrapper. So I believe that `ReadDirectoryChangesW` is going to have the same problem.

Comment: no, `ReadDirectoryChangesW` and `NtNotifyChangeDirectoryFile` not have such problems.

Comment: Re: `ReadDirectoryChangesW` (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw): "The function does not report changes to the specified directory itself."

Comment: I don't follow, `FindNextChangeNotification` just calls `NtNotifyChangeDirectoryFile`. @VladFeinstein That's also what the documentation of `FindFirstChangeNotification` says. @RbMm so what happens with `ReadDirectoryChangesW` if the folder is deleted? It feels like an internal event is not reset, but I didn't debug the kernel.

Comment: must be error returned `STATUS_DELETE_PENDING` (*A non close operation has been requested of a file object with a delete pending.*) from call to `NtNotifyChangeDirectoryFile` and as result `FindNextChangeNotification` also must return error (access denied) . think you bad log

Comment: @RbMm that's not what I get. Windows 10.0.19043.1165. Here's my output with the code: i.imgur.com/7q7Yf8z.png do you get something else?

Comment: @Paul - yes, of course else. all ok in my test

Comment: I updated the question. I found out that the behavior only happens when the folder is moved to the recycle bin.

Answer (score 2):

You have the while(true) loop. Of course, it will be an infinite loop.
You need to check the return value (b) in the loop condition in order to quit on FALSE value.

Update according to the change in the question:
Moving the file to the recycle bin is not "strict removing", it is moving only. So, the folder still exists, but in another place, in the recycle bin, so no notifications should arrive on such a move. I don't have the solution at the moment, so I would suggest to monitor this folder from the upper folder using the FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME parameter and tracking this folder name to make sure that it is not moved. But in this case you could be forced to distinguish between moving to recycle bin and another place and so on...

Comment: There's no FALSE value returned. And of course it's always an infinite loop, but if the folder is deleted, it starts looping without delays. Run the code to see how it behaves.

Comment: @Paul, just tested on Windows 10. When the folder is deleted, the FindNextChangeNotification returns FALSE and in the next loop it gets to the WaitForSingleObject which waits for a new event, but no events could occur since the folder is removed and this was signaled by previous FindNextChangeNotification.
Maybe something else affects the behavior if your version which is out of the scope of the provided code.
You may send me zip of the project to email (my first and last names separated by period at google.com) so that I could take a look or just share it.

Comment: I also test on Windows 10. Here's my output: https://i.imgur.com/7q7Yf8z.png do you get something else?

Comment: @Paul - by idea, if folder really deleted you must got 0 5 output (`GetLastError()` is very confused here, better report `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` - `STATUS_DELETE_PENDING` )

Comment: @Paul - yes, i guess that folder was not really deleted but moved. strange - in this case must no be notifications at all i think. however if you want research problem - use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` or `NtNotifyChangeDirectoryFile` and look what real notification you get and on which file. may be you better understand problem after this and that `FindNextChangeNotification` not more simply

Comment: @Paul, well, moving the file to the recycle bin is not "strict removing", it is moving only. So, the folder still exists, but in another place, in the recycle bin, so no notifications should arrive on such a move.
I don't have the solution at the moment, but I would suggest to monitor this folder from the upper folder using the FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME parameter and tracking this folder name to make sure that it is not moved.
But in this case you could be forced to distinguish between moving to recycle bin and another place and so on.

Comment: On Windows 7, I get no notification when moving the directory to the recycle bin. When writing to a file in the directory, I get the output `1 0` and when I delete the directory directly or from the recycle bin, I get the output `0 5`, which is the code for `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: @Paul If the directory is deleted, your monitor will break, which you can detect with error handling so you can then close the monitor.  The code you have shown has no error handling at all. But if the folder is just moved to the Recycle Bin, then you will likely have to monitor the Recycle Bin itself for changes (you can query the contents of the Recycle Bin using [this code](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110830-00/?p=9773)) so you can then stop monitoring the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You should watch for the changes in the parent directory as well. The example shows how to wait for two (or more) events:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/obtaining-directory-change-notifications

If your directory is deleted - `FindCloseChangeNotification` the handle; if it is created - re-open it.

Comment: Does it really solve the issue? What if the parent directory is deleted?

Comment: @Paul - monitor up to the root?

Comment: I don't feel like it's a good solution, I might end up monitoring a huge amount of files in these folders just in case my folder gets removed. Surely an overkill for me.

Comment: @Paul can you check the return value from `WaitForSingleObject`? Is it `WAIT_FAILED`?

Comment: It's `WAIT_OBJECT_0`.

Comment: @Paul I actually do NOT see any notification after I move the folder to a recycling bin. Even better: after restoring it, the notifications still work